# Elasticsearch exact matching doesn't work correctly

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I'm using elasticsearch for logging. I have an index named "query_index" that has four interior fields. I use the following mapping to create this index:

```
POST
/query_index/queries

{
  "mappings": {
    "queries": {
      "properties": {
        "query": {
          "type": "string",
          "store": true 
        },
          "exact_match":{
            "type":"string",
              "index":"not_analyzed"
          },
          "search_type": {
            "type" : "string",
              "store": true
          },
        "search_engine": {
            "type" : "string",
              "store": true
          }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

As you see the 2nd field, I put "exact_match" as `not_analyzed` field in order to retrieve exact match queries.

Let's say that I hold two documents in this index:

```
{
    "query": "Barack Obama",
    "exact_match": "Barack Obama",
    "search_engine": "google",
    "search_type": "api"
}


{
    "query": "Barack",
    "exact_match": "Barack",
    "search_engine": "google",
    "search_type": "api"
}
```

Now I want to retrieve only the second document. So I use the following query:

```
Post
/query_index/queries/_search

{"query":
            {"bool":
                {"must":
                    [
                      { "match": { "exact_match": "Barack" }},
                      { "match": { "search_engine": "google" }},
                      { "match": { "search_type": "api" }}
                    ]
                }
            }

}
```

But after running the above query, both the two documents are retrieved while I expect the second document to be retrieved. I almost searched entire Stack, but I got no result of what I'm supposed to do.

**UPDATE:**

```
GET
/query_index/_mapping
{
"query_index": {
"mappings": {
"queries": {
"properties": {
"exact_match": {
"type": "text",
"fields": {
"keyword": {
"type": "keyword",
"ignore_above": 256
}
}
},
"mappings": {
"properties": {
"queries": {
"properties": {
"properties": {
"properties": {
"exact_match": {
"properties": {
"index": {
"type": "text",
"fields": {
"keyword": {
"type": "keyword",
"ignore_above": 256
}
}
},
"type": {
"type": "text",
"fields": {
"keyword": {
"type": "keyword",
"ignore_above": 256
}
}
}
}
},
"query": {
"properties": {
"store": {
"type": "boolean"
},
"type": {
"type": "text",
"fields": {
"keyword": {
"type": "keyword",
"ignore_above": 256
}
}
}
}
},
"search_engine": {
"properties": {
"store": {
"type": "boolean"
},
"type": {
"type": "text",
"fields": {
"keyword": {
"type": "keyword",
"ignore_above": 256
}
}
}
}
},
"search_type": {
"properties": {
"store": {
"type": "boolean"
},
"type": {
"type": "text",
"fields": {
"keyword": {
"type": "keyword",
"ignore_above": 256
}
}
}
}
}
}
}
}
}
}
},
"query": {
"type": "text",
"fields": {
"keyword": {
"type": "keyword",
"ignore_above": 256
}
}
},
"search_engine": {
"type": "text",
"fields": {
"keyword": {
"type": "keyword",
"ignore_above": 256
}
}
},
"search_type": {
"type": "text",
"fields": {
"keyword": {
"type": "keyword",
"ignore_above": 256
}
}
}
}
}
}
}
}
```

Comment: Use `term` filter not `match`. `term` is not analyzing the input, while `match` does.

Comment: False.  Term analyzes the input.

Comment: I second Andrei. `term` doesn't analyze the input while `match` will try to match `barack` instead of `Barack`.

Comment: I already have tested all the possibilities including what you say. But I got the same result. @AndreiStefan

Comment: Then are you sure you are searching in the right index? Are you sure the mapping of the index you are searching into is the one you think it is?

Comment: Where are you running the search query? Sense? curl? Something else? What's the complete command?

Comment: I think your POST command is wrong, btw. That will create a document, not update a mapping.

Comment: Yes, I'm sure. document are stored in `query_index`. @AndreiStefan

Comment: I work with POSTMAN chrome extension. @AndreiStefan

Comment: Then `GET /query_index/_mapping` please and post it here.

Comment: And the correct command to put that mapping is `PUT /query_index
{
  "mappings": {
    "queries": {
      "properties": {
        "query": {`

Comment: Which version of elasticsearch are you using? I have tried the example provided by you and it's giving me right results. 
By checking the mappings stored in elasticsearch, **exact_match** field is stored as a keyword.
You can also try to change the type from string to keyword for confirmation.

Comment: @AndreiStefan Oops. The problem might be solved! I put the mapping using POST command :(. Is it wrong?

Comment: Yes, as I mentioned. You need PUT and the command I provided.

Comment: @DanishAmjad I use version 5.2.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct index creation command with that specific mapping is with `PUT` and not `POST`. With `POST` you just create a document in that index which automatically will create some fields structure inside the index.

The correct command to create the index with this specific mapping is:

```
PUT /query_index
{
  "mappings": {
    "queries": {
      "properties": {
        "query": {
          "type": "string",
          "store": true
        },
        "exact_match": {
          "type": "string",
          "index": "not_analyzed"
        },
        "search_type": {
          "type": "string",
          "store": true
        },
        "search_engine": {
          "type": "string",
          "store": true
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: No problem. Happy to help.